# Call to a member function follow() on integer

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to save users to a followers table when one user follows another. When I try to get one user to follow another I get

> Call to a member function follow() on integer

whenever I try to follow another user.

***Follow Button/Form***

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'follow_user']) !!}

  {!! Form::hidden('id', $user->id) !!}

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Follow {{$user->name}}</button>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

***Route***

```
Route::post('/follow', [
    'as' => 'follow_user', 'uses' => 'FollowersController@store'
]);
```

***Followers Controller***

```
public function store()
{
    $user1 = Auth::user()->id;        
    $user2 = Input::get('id');
    $user1->follow($user2);

    return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
}
```

***Methods I am using in User model***

```
function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'followers', 'user_id', 'follower_id');
}

function follow(User $user) {
    $this->followers()->attach($user->id);
}

function unfollow(User $user) {
    $this->followers()->detach($user->id);
}
```

Comment: so what's your error again?

Comment: I am getting 'Call to a member function follow() on integer' whenever I try to follow another user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to run `follow()` on a ID, not the User object (as you probably want).

This returns an integer:

```
$user1 = Auth::user()->id;
```

Maybe you want something like this:

```
$user1 = Auth::user();        
$user2 = Input::get('id');
$user1->follow(User::find($user2));
```

Thanks to @blackpla9ue for the fix.

Comment: This returns another error for me. 'Argument 1 passed to App\User::follow() must be an instance of App\User, string given'.

Comment: Last line should be `$user1->follow(Auth::find($user2));`

Comment: Yep, I miss that part. Thanks, @blackpla9ue

Comment: Needed to change ```Auth::find($user2)``` to ```User::find($user2)```